# Adapt.js like functionality for Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I need to have different javascript executed for different screen sizes or if the window si resized. basically exactly like adpat.js serves CSS i need to serve JS. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Basically for anything below 840px in width, i need to have something like this :

```
 $('div.something').attr('id',$(this).val());
```

this is how i render my css right now so i want basically to do the same but with javascript files/functions

```
var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
      path: 'http://yourpath.com/assets/',
      dynamic: true,
      range: [
        '0px    to 480px  = mobile.css',
        '481px  to 840px  = middle.css',
        '841px  to 1440px = large.css',
        '1441px           = xlarge.css'
      ]
    };
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad design to me. The problem is that one can not simply "unload" javascript without page reloading. What you can actually use is some sort of conditional loader for javascript try http://yepnopejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason you can't do this?

```
if($(document).width() < 840) {
 $('div.something').attr('id',$(this).val());
}
```